# Duplicate logs when calling logging.basicConfig

Tags: python-3.6, python-logging

##### Problem: When I call logging.basicConfig in addition to configuring my own logger, I get duplicate logs

- I'm running python 3.6.8
- Easy fix is to not call logging.basicConfig - however, I am importing modules that call it
- I don't understand why the logs are being duplicated. I have checked the number of handlers on the logger and there is only one handler

Code to reproduce the issue

```
import logging
import sys

# create a logger, add a handler and a formatter
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
log.setLevel(logging.INFO)
handler = logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout)
handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter("%(levelname)s:%(name)s:%(message)s"))
log.addHandler(handler)

# call basicConfig
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO) # logs not duplicated if this line is removed

# create a log message
log.info("hello world")

# verify the number of handlers on the logger
print(f" num_handlers = {len(log.handlers)}")

#>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
#INFO:__main__:hello world
#INFO:__main__:hello world
#num_handlers = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python loggers exist in a hierarchy. There is a root logger (accessible with `root = logging.getLogger()`) which is always at the root/top of the hierarchy, and which is configured when `basicConfig` is being called. Every other logger propagates their logs up the hierarchy, so every log will eventually reach the root logger (more exactly: the root loggers handlers).

One possible solution is to stop your logger propagating:

```
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
log.propagate = False
```